# How do I make 3D in pyglet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, 3d, pyglet

I was trying to create using OpenGL, Python and pyglet, a flat triangle in 3D space, I saw some tutorials on the internet, some videos on YouTube, and in the end I wrote this code down there, the problem is that it did not work as I expected, I thought that if I tried to spin, I would see the triangle turning flat, and when I walked away, the triangle did not have to diminish?

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

config = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=8)
tela = pyglet.window.Window(height=500, width=500, config=config)

glViewport(0,0,500,500)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(35,1,0.1,1000)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

@tela.event
def on_draw():
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex3f(10,10,0)
    glVertex3f(100,10,0)
    glVertex3f(50,100,0)
    glEnd()
    glFlush()

@tela.event
def on_key_press(s,m):
    tela.clear()
    if s == pyglet.window.key.W:
        glTranslatef(0,0,1)
    if s == pyglet.window.key.S:
        glTranslatef(0,0,-1)
    if s == pyglet.window.key.A:
        glRotatef(1,0,1,0)
    if s == pyglet.window.key.D:
        glRotatef(-1,0,1,0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

When I run the code this appears:

[image]

And when I try to spin the scenario it happens:

[image]

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization of the viewport and the sting pf the projection and model view matrix is useless

> ```
> glViewport(0,0,500,500)
> glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
> glLoadIdentity()
> gluPerspective(35,1,0.1,1000)
> glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
> ```

because the viewport and an orthographic projection is set when the application is started.

See [pyglet - The OpenGL interface](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/gl.html):

> [...] pyglet sets up the viewport and an orthographic projection on each window automatically.

If you would use the perspective projection

> ```
> gluPerspective(35,1,0.1,1000)
> ```

then the triangle would disappear, because it would be clipped by the near plane of the perspective projection (`0.1`).

---

To solve the issue, put the setup of perspective projection to the `draw` event:

```py
@tela.event
def on_draw():

    tela.clear()

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.1, 100)
```

> I thought that if I tried to spin, I would see the triangle turning flat, and when I walked away, the triangle did not have to diminish?

In view space, the x axis points from the left to the right and the y axis points from the bottom to the top.
To rotate in the XY plane, you have to rotate around the Z axis.

Define a position and an Y-angle for the triangle. The Z coordinate has to be negative and the distance to the object has to be in between the near and far plane. If near is 0.1 and far is 100, then:

```
0.1 <= -z <= 100
```

e.g.

```
pos = [0, 0, -20]
rot_y = 0
```

Manipulate the position and the angle in the event:

```py
@tela.event
def on_key_press(s,m):

    global pos_z, rot_y

    if s == pyglet.window.key.W:
        pos[2] -= 1
    if s == pyglet.window.key.S:
        pos[2] += 1
    if s == pyglet.window.key.A:
        rot_y += 5
    if s == pyglet.window.key.D:
        rot_y -= 5
```

Apply the translation and the rotation to the model view matrix stack in `draw`:

```py
@tela.event
def on_draw():

    global pos_z, rot_y

    # [...]

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glTranslatef(*pos)
    glRotatef(rot_y, 0, 1, 0)
```

Draw an object which is arranged around (0, 0, 0). Note the position of the object is set by `pos` and in perspective  projection the origin (0, 0, 0) is in the center of the window:

```py
glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
glVertex3f(-5,-5,0)
glVertex3f(5,-5,0)
glVertex3f(0,5,0)
glEnd()
```

Full code with the suggested changes applied:

[image]

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

pos = [0, 0, -20]
rot_y = 0

config = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=8)
tela = pyglet.window.Window(height=500, width=500, config=config)

@tela.event
def on_draw():

    global pos_z, rot_y

    tela.clear()

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.1, 100)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glTranslatef(*pos)
    glRotatef(rot_y, 0, 1, 0)

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex3f(-5,-5,0)
    glVertex3f(5,-5,0)
    glVertex3f(0,5,0)
    glEnd()

    glFlush()

@tela.event
def on_key_press(s,m):

    global pos_z, rot_y

    if s == pyglet.window.key.W:
        pos[2] -= 1
    if s == pyglet.window.key.S:
        pos[2] += 1
    if s == pyglet.window.key.A:
        rot_y += 5
    if s == pyglet.window.key.D:
        rot_y -= 5

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: I'm trying to rotate the triangle on the y-axis, as if it were a rotating 3D object.

Comment: @ArthurSally I see, I changed the answer.

Comment: How to speed this up?  The frame rate is very low.

Comment: @BazyliDebowski Do not use legacy OpenGL. Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader). A good tutorial is [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)